# Unable to calculate sonarqube code coverage even though nothing has changed in the project on Gitlab

Tags: gitlab, sonarqube, pipeline, code-coverage

The pipeline on the Gitlab includes the sonarqube check step. And this particular pipeline works automatically at certain time intervals. Although there was no change in the project, I got the following error. What could be the reason?

```
INFO: EXECUTION FAILURE
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
INFO: Total time: 9.987s
INFO: Final Memory: 17M/360M
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
ERROR: Error during SonarScanner execution
ERROR: QUALITY GATE STATUS: FAILED - View details on http://sonarqube......

In the link I have  on overall code coverage is less than 80% error. But this is not correct because when I rerun the pipeline it works properly.
```

Here is the gitlab yml

```
sonarqube-check:
  stage: check
  script:
    - '& $SONAR_SCANNER_EXE begin /k:$SONAR_KEY /n:$SONAR_KEY /d:sonar.host.url=$SONAR_HOST_URL /d:sonar.login=$SONAR_TOKEN /d:sonar.cs.opencover.reportsPaths=coverage.opencover.xml /d:sonar.cs.nunit.reportsPaths=TestResult.xml /d:sonar.qualitygate.wait=true /d:sonar.qualitygate.timeout=180'
    - 'nuget restore -configfile $NUGET_CONFIG_PATH' # restore NuGet dependencies
    - 'msbuild -p:Configuration=Release -p:IncludeSymbols=true -p:SymbolPackageFormat=snupkg .\$VS_SOLUTION_FILE'
    - '& $SONAR_SCANNER_EXE end /d:sonar.login=$SONAR_TOKEN'
  tags:
    - cf-aws-windows-runner
  only:
    - main
    - merge_requests
  dependencies:
    - build_job
```

And sonaqrqube info is here
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aUsp6.png)

The important point is I am not getting this error all the time, nothing changed but sonarqube can not calculate the test coverage of the project sometimes. Could you please help me?

I am not getting this error all the time, nothing changed but sonarqube can not calculate the test coverage of the project sometimes when I rerun the pipeline it works properly.

Answer (score 1):

SonarQube does not calculate coverage, it just reports what you give it via `sonar.cs.opencover.reportsPaths`.

You should check if coverage.opencover.xml file shows the same coverage or not between your Gitlab runs whenever the quality gate shows something you don't expect.

If you want quicker help, you should go to https://community.sonarsource.com/ and submit your thread/question there, not StackOverflow.